# How to remove valid and duplicated rows in dataframe based on one column?

Tags: r

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
    x = sample(0:2, 10, replace = T),
    y = sample(0:2, 10, replace = T)
)
df[df==2] <- NA

df=df[!duplicated(df$y),]
print(df)
```

The output of above script is:

```
  x  y
1  0 NA
2 NA  1
5 NA  0
```

I want to keep all `NA`,only compare the valid value.
The expect result is:

```
    x  y
1   0 NA
2  NA  1
3   1 NA
5  NA  0
6   0 NA
10  1 NA
```

How to do it? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please can you include a `set.seed` in your code _e.g._ `set.seed(123)`. Otherwise the values generated by `sample` are not reproducible.

Comment: Provided I understood correctly this seems to be a duplicate post of the one linked to. Please take a look; will re-open if this is a different issue.

Comment: `df[!duplicated(df$y) | is.na(df$y),]`

Comment: @RonakShah's comment is better.

Comment: Actually, in your case you can use `incomparables` argument. `df[!duplicated(df$y, incomparables = NA), ]` gives the same output.